# Show divs depending on which button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I click on button1 I get content1 and then if I click button2 I get content2 but under content1. Content1 is still visible. And this is a problem. That contents should be show in the same place but depending on which button is pressed. So, if I click on button1 I should get content1 and then if I click button2 I should get content2 instead of content1. Can you help me? This is my code:

```
<script src="public/javascripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <div id="list" >
    <input id="Button1" class="links" type="button" value="Trasa Kraków - Warszawa"   onclick="ShowHide()" data-showdiv="Content1" /> 
    <input id="Button2" class="links" type="button" value="Trasa Kraków - Wieliczka"  data-showdiv="Content2" />
    <input id="Button3" type="button" value="Trasa Nowy York - Pekin"   onclick=":D" />
    <input id="Button4" type="button" value="Show Status"   onclick="ShowHide()" />
    <input id="Button5" type="button" value="Show Status"   onclick="ShowHide()" />
</div>

<div id="Content1" class="divs" style="display:none" >
    <img src="http://kobylnica.pl/pic/item,69,1,x.jpg" alt="Tekst alternatywny" width="500" height "600"/>
    Miejsce na wyświetlenie filmiku i opisu trasy </div>

<div id="Content2" class="divs" style="display:none" >
    <img src="http://cdn32.se.smcloud.net/t/photos/111759/robie_rowery_z_drewna.jpg" alt="Tekst alternatywny" width="500" height "600"/>
    Miejsce na wyświetlenie filmiku i opisu trasy </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".links").click(function(){
    $("divs:visible").hide();
    $("#"+$(this).attr("data-showdiv")).show();
});

</script>
```

Comment: $("divs:visible").hide(); should be $(".divs:visible").hide();

Comment: @StaticVoid - post as an answer, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("divs:visible").hide();` should be `$(".divs:visible").hide();`

Answer (score 0):

On top of what StaticVoid answered, you also were missing class="links" on one of the buttons.

```
<script src="public/javascripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <div id="list" >
    <input id="Button1" class="links" type="button" value="Trasa Kraków - Warszawa"   onclick="ShowHide()" data-showdiv="Content1" /> 
    <input id="Button2" class="links" type="button" value="Trasa Kraków - Wieliczka"  data-showdiv="Content2" />
    <input id="Button3" class="links" type="button" value="Trasa Nowy York - Pekin"   onclick=":D" />
    <input id="Button4" type="button" value="Show Status"   onclick="ShowHide()" />
    <input id="Button5" type="button" value="Show Status"   onclick="ShowHide()" />
</div>

<div id="Content1" class="divs" style="display:none" >
    <img src="http://kobylnica.pl/pic/item,69,1,x.jpg" alt="Tekst alternatywny" width="500" height "600"/>
    Miejsce na wyświetlenie filmiku i opisu trasy </div>

<div id="Content2" class="divs" style="display:none" >
    <img src="http://cdn32.se.smcloud.net/t/photos/111759/robie_rowery_z_drewna.jpg" alt="Tekst alternatywny" width="500" height "600"/>
    Miejsce na wyświetlenie filmiku i opisu trasy </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".links").click(function(){
    $(".divs:visible").hide();
    $("#"+$(this).attr("data-showdiv")).show();
});

</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RMbPF/

Comment: OP doesn't mention button 3